# Verify this identity: $1-\frac{\sin^2x}{1−\cos x}=\cos x$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

This doesn't look like a though one but still i'm having a rough time with it, i guess i'm just doing something wrong but i can't find what i'm doing wrong.
I got as close as $1-\cos x$ but i can't get to the answer i need.

Comment: the identity to verify should be $1-\frac{\sin^2 x}{1-\cos x} = -\cos x$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$1-\frac { \sin ^{ 2 }{ x }  }{ 1-\cos { x }  } =1-\frac { \sin ^{ 2 }{ x } \left( 1+\cos { x }  \right)  }{ (1-\cos { x }) \left( 1+\cos { x }  \right)  } $$

Comment: so:
1-((1-cos^2x)(1+cosx))/((1-cosx)(1+cosx))
Then the square cuts with (1-cosx) and the (1+cosx) cut with one another and i get
1-1-cosx=-cosx
is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{\sin^2x}{1-\cos x}=\frac{1-\cos^2x}{1-\cos x}=\frac{(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x)}{1-\cos x}=1+\cos x$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\frac{\sin x}{1 - \cos x} = \cot \frac x2$. Then we have
$$ 1 - \sin x \cot \frac x2 = 1 - 2\sin \frac x2 \cos \frac x2 \cot \frac x2 =1 - 2 \cos^2 \frac x2 = - \cos x.$$